# What happens when run in command line: geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development

I set up geth and then I run: geth. It seems to be downloading something ? So what the heck is it doing ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Geth is downloading (syncing) state of Ethereum blockchain (such as all transactions / blocks / objects).

This article has more details : https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-sync-an-ethereum-node-using-geth-and-ethereum-wallet-81423d42a583